# How to have scanf ignore extraneous text from an input file?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm attempting to give a program input of the following form:

```
11 22 @3
30 2  @^
1  4  @B    asdfghj
```

However, there are several lines (like the last) that have extra text in them. I'm trying to have the program ignore them to no avail.

Below is my current code:

```
int x_coord;
int y_coord;
char type[3];

do(grid[y_coord][x_coord]=type[1]);
while(scanf("%d %d %s",&x_coord,&y_coord,type)!=EOF);{
for(i=1; i<=30;i++){

 for(j=1; j<=30;j++){
   printf("%c",grid[i][j]);
 }
  printf("\n");
 }
 }
```

I've tried to add an extra parameter`%*s` to scanf to attempt to catch any extra text, but I couldn't get it to run.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to handle the extra text in the input file?

Comment: Read each line with `fgets` then use `sscanf`.

Comment: http://ideone.com/Wjl2Nl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop seems very oddly formed.

```
do(grid[y_coord][x_coord]=type[1]);
while(scanf("%d %d %s",&x_coord,&y_coord,type)!=EOF);
```

Is `y_coord`, `x_coord` and `type` initialized properly for the assignment to work?

Also, `scanf()` will return the number of elements successfully scanned. You can use that for additional error checking.

In any case, if your input is well-formed, then you can use the following format string:

```
scanf("%d %d %s%*[^\n]%*c",&x_coord,&y_coord,type)
```

After parsing the first three arguments, this will discard anything that is not a newline character, and then discard the newline itself.

Using `scanf()` is error prone because badly formed input can cause scanning to jam or unexpected errors as unintended portions of the input get interpreted incorrectly. For line delimited input, it is better to read in the entire line first with `fgets()` and then parse the line with `sscanf()`.

Comment: Ah, I was really close to this, just missed the the last `%*c`. I'm new to programming, so I found a loop that worked and just used it. Is there another loop that would work a bit better?

Comment: The parentheses around the assignment statement is misleading. It makes it look like you believe the `do` is followed by a predicate check, when in fact the parenthetical statement is the body of the do-while loop. It would be more clear (and probably more correct) to use a regular while loop, and let the assignment be the body of the while loop.